# Normalize MySQL Database by assigning unique IDs to certain columns, then move relevant information to new table

Tags: mysql, pandas, database-normalization

I have one table with all of the pertinent information I need for my database with the columns: CompanyName, StoreLocation, StoreNumber, ItemName, and ItemModel

[image: One Table ERD]

I want to move the column `CompanyName` to its own `Company` Table that will contain a `CompanyID` and the `CompanyName` in its own table, as well as moving the `StoreLocation` and `StoreNumber` columns to their own `Store` Table. I need to assign unique (auto-incrementing is fine) IDs for each company and for each store while maintaining foreign-primary key integrity for the IDs in each table. After making these changes the database ERD should look something like this:

[image: Normalized ERD]

Here is the expected output for all of the data in the one table:

[image: One Table Output]

And lastly, here is the expected output when all of the tables are normalized:

[image: Normalized Output]

What is the best way to go about doing this? I can use Python's Pandas if necessary, but was wondering the best way to add this normalization in to avoid the duplication of many values if it were to stay in one table.

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: You can do this entirely in MySQL. You can start with `INSERT INTO company (companyname) SELECT DISTINCT companyname FROM originalTable;`

Comment: I figured that was the best way to start. What would be the best way to insert each unique companyID back into each row of the store table though?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in Python?  3 simple queries can solve this problem.

Comment: @Eric I was definitely overthinking it. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)  Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is not clear--What is your question? If you are asking what tables to use, how to normalize is too broad, give your steps following a reference. If you are asking how to get the data into the tables, what have you tried? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.PS Replacing values by others that are ids is not normalization. Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by others with subsets of its columns. PS If an item has a name & model independent of its stores then you probably want to drop storeid from Item & add StoreItem with storeid & itemid pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with 3 SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO company (companyname)
SELECT DISTINCT companyname
FROM originalTable;

INSERT INTO store (storelocation, storenumber, companyid)
SELECT DISTINCT o.storelocation, o.storenumber, c.companyid
FROM originalTable o
JOIN company c ON o.companyname = c.companyname;

INSERT INTO item (itemname, itemmodel, storeid)
SELECT o.itemname, o.itemmodel, s.storeid
FROM originalTable o
JOIN store s ON s.storelocation = o.storelocation AND s.storenumber = o.storenumber
JOIN company c ON s.companyid = s.companyid AND o.companyname = c.companyname;
```

The join with `company` in the third query is necessary if the original table can have duplicate location+storenumber for stores from different companies.

Comment: Wow Barmar that was amazing how simple you made it. This worked like a charm, thank you so much!